# Accessing external data in a field

Tags: entities

When creating a content type I would like to have a field type that could be used to call a rest service or make a db call to an external database.  Does this exist?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, What I was thinking when you add a new field to a content type could it field type of Service or External Data source. Then you could create a service call to retrieve the info be it a rest service or a database call.  I am very new to drupal so there may already be an answer. I know you can put a hack in to do it but was looking for a solution before I spent to much time on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no, there isn't a module out there to do this. I have seen something similar done in the past though, where a node would have an id of some sort provided, and a module would connect to an external service to load in information for the node.

I suspect you might want to think about writing a custom module to do this. If you haven't taken a look at https://drupal.org/developing/modules yet you might want to. Just remember when modifying functionality of Drupal you should never hack the core, but create/use a module instead.

I think what your gonna want to do is architect a way to know what you need to pull and from where, then use hook_node_view to change/add the data you pull from your DB/external service (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7)